# Why is the activation energy of combustion so large compared with regular bonding?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, physical-chemistry, molecules, quantum-chemistry

I wanted to know why combustion requires an activation energy and I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_oxygen#Reaction) article (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion#Reaction_mechanism) too). It says that molecular oxygen ground state is a triplet state (according to Hund's rules), and that prevents it from reacting with singlet molecules. It still says nothing about bonding in an excited state (where the product is not a singlet).

Now consider a free oxygen atom and another oxygen atom during the formation of dioxygen. Since each oxygen atom is a triplet then it's possible for the direct product to have spin 2, 1 or 0 (according to [Wigner's rule](https://books.google.com/books?id=kyMDCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA180&dq=wigner+rule+chemistry&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wigner%20rule%20chemistry&f=false)). So in principle I expect to see either an excited oxygen molecule (not a triplet) or a triplet. The excited states could not deexcite directly since it would be a forbidden transition, but they can through collisions. Is this paragraph correct?

In any case, what makes the formation of oxygen molecules from oxygen atoms "easier" than combustion in the absence of activation energy? why can't oxygen and singlet molecules (fuel) bond to form an excited state and then deexcite to initiate combustion? or is the fact that a triplet and a singlet can't give a singlet product (that's the preferred state of the intermediate products from what I have read) a big impediment?

Comment: What are the Gibbs free energies of the system? What pathway is more stable or more favorable?

Comment: @tpg2114 That's the thing, combustion is very complicated from what I read. My question has more to do with getting a qualitative explanation. Specifically, is the second paragraph ok, mainly the part about the Wigner's rule. If that's ok then I could see why triplet oxygen wouldn't work as well.

Comment: It is complicated, but the only thing I can say is consider what state minimizes the free energy of the system. All kinds of exotic things are "possible" but nature will prefer the one that is most stable. I don't know about Winner's rule so I cannot answer directly.